# Not enough values to unpack

Tags: python

> You are given two arrays `a` and `b`, each consisting of `n` positive integers, and an integer `x`. Please determine if one can rearrange the elements of `b` so that `ai+bi≤x` holds for each `i` (`1≤i≤n`).

This is [codeforces 1445A question](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1445/A). Tests are separated by blank line

input

```
4
3 4
1 2 3
1 1 2

2 6
1 4
2 5

4 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4

1 5
5
5
```

output

```
Yes
Yes
No
No
```

I wrote this following code in python. After submitting in codeforces I got an runtime error. And when i gave input manually code worked fine. What is wrong with this code? when reading an input file? how to fix this?

```
import sys

def get_list():
    return list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()))

def get_ints():
    return map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())

tests = int(input())
while tests != 0:
    size, limit = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    p = get_list()
    q = get_list()
    for i in range(size):
        if p[i] + q[size-i-1] > limit:
            print("No")
            break
    else:
        print("Yes")
    tests = tests - 1
```

Comment: `input().split()` must not be returning two numbers. Can you show what the input looks like?

Comment: You never use the `get_ints()` function. And why are you using `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input()`?

Comment: 4
3 4
1 2 3
2 4 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here

```
size, limit = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

You need to ignore empty lines between each test

So, start with this

```
def test(l1, l2, l3):
  ''' returns Yes or No '''
  pass  # TODO: implement this

tests = int(input())
while tests > 0:
    numbers = get_list()
    if not numbers:
        continue
    p = get_list()
    q = get_list()
    print(test(numbers, p, q))
    tests -= 1
```

Also, I suspect your `print("Yes")` is not correctly intended to be within the loop

Answer (score 0):

I think in the test input there is a blank line that is expected between tests so when you're trying to `split` it, you will get a empty list `[]` instead of `[<int 1>, <int 2>]` then unpack and assign it to `size` and `limit`, which will cause the run time exception. To workaround this, I think you can store the input for size and limit into variable (`inp` in this case) and check if it is an empty line or not. If it does, then you simple skip it and get the next line input

```
inp = input()
if inp.strip() == '':
    continue
size, limit = [int(x) for x in inp.split()]
```

So you would get the below code

```
import sys

def get_list():
    return list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()))

def get_ints():
    return map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())

tests = int(input())
while tests != 0:
    inp = input()
    if inp.strip() == '':
        continue
    size, limit = [int(x) for x in inp.split()]
    p = get_list()
    q = get_list()
    for i in range(size):
        if p[i] + q[size-i-1] > limit:
            print("No")
            break
    else:
        print("Yes")
    tests = tests - 1
```

Comment: if i replace p = getlist and q =getlist by  
p = [ int (x) for x in input().split]
q = [int(x) for x in input().split()] will the code work?

Comment: Yeah, I think that should work

Answer (score 0):

It's uncommon for codeforces problems to include newlines between queries, but that's what's throwing you off. You can add

```
if tests > 0:
    input()
```

at the end of your while loop to get it to run properly. Note that the arrays [here](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1445/A) have no more than 1000 elements, there's no need to use `sys.stdin.readline()`.